# Decoding base64String value returns nil

Tags: ios, swift, base64, nsdata, decoding

I am trying to get an UIImage from base64String but I am facing an interesting problem. Even though the encoded string is full, decoding it returns nil.

```
   let base64String = imageFilePath as! String
   print(base64String) // returns encoded value

   let decodedData = NSData(base64EncodedString: base64String, options: NSDataBase64DecodingOptions(rawValue: 0))
   print(decodedData) // returns nil
```

Edit: It goes like

> 24wKiOQeetKPWmsx3AjtQMe+cDApoOTinCTOOKUsF5osIbtK800E5yKRySeeKFf ZQA5m79KkjYHr1qMupHWkbJGVoGTE0majXceT0qQkAUCGEUo5GKYOT81S5AOKEND
>   WUg0wg9BUu4dKibAOKYCAHFKOCCaQ9cGkBzQApbk5o3D7p/A0mRS9e1AD1BPSnCN
>   RzQnA5pjHPFMdhWcgbVHFSggr0/

Comment: you can try with `let decodedData = NSData(base64EncodedString: base64String, options:NSDataBase64DecodingOptions.IgnoreUnknownCharacters)`

Comment: That's the answer solving my problem. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Manuel please add it as an answer and I accept it

Comment: I've added the answer. Thanks

Comment: @Manuel you just saved my day !! man i was quite amused how it is Working , and  thank for asking the question senty.

Comment: if you can explain why is this  happening , Please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this code:

`let decodedData = NSData(base64EncodedString: base64String, options:NSDataBase64DecodingOptions.IgnoreUnknownCharacters)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use these functions to encode and decode Base64 Strings

```
static func encodeBase64(input: String)->String{

            let utf8str = input.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            return utf8str!.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0))   
        }
static func decodeBase64(input: String)->String{

        let base64Decoded = NSData(base64EncodedString: input, options:   NSDataBase64DecodingOptions(rawValue: 0))
            .map({ NSString(data: $0, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) })

        return base64Decoded as! String

    }
```

Comment: I added the console log for my base64String. Is there something wrong I am doing?

Answer (score 0):

Probably your `imageFilePath` is not a Base64 string. Print it and check if it contains anything except alphanumeric characters and `+` and `/` signs.

Comment: I edited my question and put the log of base64String. What do you think?